# Problem downloading Oracle JDK 7

Tags: java, software-installation, jdk, oracle

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm trying to install Oracle JDK 7. When I tried to directly download the jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz from the official website, the download started and after downloading couple of MBs it stopped (you can try it as well, worked the same way for a friend).
Using a guide.

led me to

```
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

which is normal, as it is downloading from the same link. Exact report [here](http://postimg.org/image/gdbym90bf/)

I tried to download and install the .rpm file. I converted it to deb and installed it. It appears as installed in the Software center, but could not find it via terminal (java -version returns suggestions for installing packages). Image from the Software center [here](http://postimg.org/image/780kh9lq3/)

I tried everything here.

and could not find anything on the internet.

Comment: What happens if you `wget` the file, do you get the same behavior where it stops downloading?

Comment: Yes, the same thing. The response is OK, but downloads just a small part of it:
2014-03-17 15:05:58 (478 MB/s) - `jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

When trying to open it, it shows it is corrupted of course.

Comment: Can you run `dpkg -L jdk`? Also, there is OpenJDK in the main archives and Oracle JDK in an existing PPA. You didn't need to convert an RPM package.

Comment: Almost certainly a server error. It's telling you that the tar.gz is 5307 bytes which is wrong, and I'm getting the same behavior. Two "302 Moved Temporarily" followed by this incorrect file.

Comment: Did you try the manual method here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use webup8's PPA. I use it for Java 8, but there's also for Java 7.

See here for Java 7

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

and here for Java 8 (both can coexist in your system)

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: Installers for [Oracle Java 7 does not work](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html). The download page has been moved and the `apt-get` cannot download the files from the Oracle servers. -- If you really need java 7, you can [download the installers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html) and/or use install [other packages](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html).